# apt-get error: "Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com' "

Tags: server, 10.04, updates

```
root@server1:~# apt-get update
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com lucid Release.gpg
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
0% [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com]
```

I can't get it work, any issues?  I use Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: First, 10.04 is almost end of life and won't be supported anymore soon.  It is recommended you upgrade.  Second, are you sure your internet works?  This doesn't appear to be an `apt` problem...

Comment: Yes, and how do I update?

Comment: You would do a fresh install.  10.04 is *really* old.

Answer (score 2):

**First comment:**

While Ubuntu **10.04.4 LTS** (Lucid Lynx) Server is still under support, until **April 2015**, you need to be planning when you transition to **12.04 LTS**.

---

**Your current problem:**

This appears to be a 'temporary' issue. You should retry the next day.

*Do you have the server configured to automatically receive security updates?*

*When did you last 'manually' (and successfully) get updates?*

---

**Possible causes:**

You may be experiencing issues with the GPG key for Lucid 'backports' and/or other outdated content. A less 'aggressive' configuration, less extra packages and other add-on elements, may be more stable and generally succeed.

Comment: Actually, they moved support for 10.04 desktop to May... See: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: I have bought this from one company, they support CentOS and ubuntu x86 10.04, I really need help thanks!

Comment: @Seth: I have assumed 'Server', not 'Desktop'.

Comment: @david6 No, desktop.

Comment: I use server, not desktop.